# How to prove that $W^n_p[0,1]$ is a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, absolute-continuity

> **Problem.** Let $1\le p<\infty$ and $n \ge 1$ and let $W^n_p[0,1]=$ the functions $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{C}$ such that $f$ has $n-1$ continuous derivatives, $f^{(n-1)}$ is absolutely continuous, and $f^{(n)} \in L^p[0,1]$. For $f$ in $W^n_p[0,1]$, define
> $$||f||:=\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\int_0^1|f^{(k)}(x)|^p ~\mathrm{d}x\right]^\frac{1}{p}$$
> Then $W^n_p[0,1]$ is a Banach space.

If we take a Cauchy sequence $(f_j)_j$ in $W^n_p[0,1]$, then it follows that $(f_j^{(k)})_j$ is Cauchy in $L^p[0,1]$ for all $k = 0, 1, \dots, n$. Hence there are $g_{k} \in L^p[0,1]$ such that $(f_j^{(k)})\to g_k$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, n$. From this how to prove that $g_k=g_0^{(k)}$ for all $k = 1, \dots, n$? Thanks.

**EDIT** I tried to proceed as follows:
$f_j \to g_0$ in $L^p$ $\implies \text{for some subsequence }f_{j_l}\to g_0$ a.e. on $[0,1]$. Then we have
$$g_0(x)= \lim f_{j_l}(x)= \lim \int_0^x f_{j_l}^{'}=\int_0^x\lim f_{j_l}^{'}=\int_0^x g_1$$
for a.e $x$ in $[0, 1]$. This implies $g_0'(x) = g_1(x)$ a.e. $x$ . Now similarly we can prove others.
Then since $f_j^{(n-1)}$ was absolutely continuous functions with $L^p$ derivatives we can use this to prove that $g_{n-1}(=g_0^{(n-1)})$ is also absolutely continuous with $L^p$ derivative. And this shows that $g_0 \in W^n_p[0,1]$.

Is there any mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Space Sobolev $W^{m,p}$ complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232969/space-sobolev-wm-p-complete)

Comment: @lc2r43 No. Actually I don't know "weak derivatives".

Comment: How do you define the derivative $f^{(n)}$ if not as weak derivative?

Comment: @daw I would define it as : $f^{(n)}(x):=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x+h)-f^{(n-1)}(x)}{h}$ for all $x$. Here $f^{(n-1)}$ is given to be differentiable with a $L^p$ derivative. Right??

Comment: No, that limit is not guaranteed to exist, and definitely not for *all* x, you should learn the definition of a weak derivative before coming back to this question

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you. I got the point.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Absolutely continuous function can definitely be studied without knowing weak derivative. Indeed, this question is so formulated so as to avoid the sobolev space notations. This has its own merit (e.g. to study calculus of variation in 1d without sobolev spaces).

Comment: Hmm. Sure, I can believe that. But the question is literally about a Sobolev space @ArcticChar

Comment: Well it's closed anyway. A similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473752/showing-that-space-of-absolutely-continuous-functions-is-banach-space), which might help you prove it without using weak derivatives.